# Get first (and last) day of month - expression simplification

Tags: sql, date, firebird

I need to get date, which was 30 (later I will use also 90 or 18O) days before first day of current (and previous) month. I wrote this, but I think it's unnecessarily complicated, so I come here for help. It's any way how can I simplify this:

```
ib_encodedate(EXTRACT(YEAR from (dateadd(-30-datediff(day from cast(EXTRACT(MONTH from CURRENT_DATE) 
|| '-1-' 
|| EXTRACT(YEAR from CURRENT_DATE) as date) to date 'now') DAY to CURRENT_DATE))), EXTRACT(MONTH from (dateadd(-30-datediff(day from cast(EXTRACT(MONTH from CURRENT_DATE) 
|| '-1-' 
|| EXTRACT(YEAR from CURRENT_DATE) as date) to date 'now') DAY to CURRENT_DATE))),EXTRACT(DAY from (dateadd(-30-datediff(day from cast(EXTRACT(MONTH from CURRENT_DATE) 
|| '-1-' 
|| EXTRACT(YEAR from CURRENT_DATE) as date) to date 'now') DAY to CURRENT_DATE))))
```

In database I have dates in `double`, so I have to use function `ib_encodedate` to convert date to `double` and compare with date in database. Function have prototype:

```
ib_encodedate(INT year, INT month, INT day)
```

The same I need to write for last day of month.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you really want 30, 90 and 180 days earlier .. or will you want 1 month, 3 months or 6 months earlier (most likely).  Of course you can easily get the last day of month by subtracting one day from the next month.

Comment: In past I used 30, 90, ... for simplification, but I think it's doesn't mind if I use 1 months, 3 months and etc

Comment: @ErstwhileIII just be aware you won't all the data in the last day of the month if you do that (unless all your times are at set to midnight)... you'll need to subtract 1 second, not an entire day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like you need something like this:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD (-EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE)+1 DAY TO CURRENT_DATE) AS FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH,
    DATEADD (-30 DAY TO DATEADD (-EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE)+1 DAY TO CURRENT_DATE)) AS A_MONTH_AGO,
    DATEADD (-90 DAY TO DATEADD (-EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE)+1 DAY TO CURRENT_DATE)) AS THREE_MONTHS_AGO,
    DATEADD (-180 DAY TO DATEADD (-EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE)+1 DAY TO CURRENT_DATE)) AS SIX_MONTHS_AGO
FROM 
    RDB$DATABASE
```

Using the function [DATEADD](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-intfunc-dateadd.html) from firebird you can easily accomplish this.

Answer (score 5):

First Day of The Date:

```
select cast(:DATA as date) - extract(day from cast(:DATA as date)) + 1 from RDB$DATABASE
```

Last Day of The Date:

```
select cast(:DATA as date) - extract(day from cast(:DATA as date)) + 32 - extract(day from (cast(:DATA as date) - extract(day from cast(:DATA as date)) + 32)) from RDB$DATABASE
```

Comment: It works even in the old firebird 1.5, in which some people like me are tied to.

Answer (score 4):

Using Firebird 2.5

First Day:

```
SELECT CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)||'-'||EXTRACT(MONTH FROM 
       CURRENT_DATE)||'-01' AS DATE) FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

Last Day:

```
SELECT DATEADD (-1 DAY TO DATEADD (1 MONTH TO CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM 
                CURRENT_DATE)||'-'||EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE)||'-01' AS DATE))) 
      FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use firebird 1.5 you can create this function which returns the last day of the month of a specified date:

`create or alter procedure LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH (
    REFERENCE_DATE date)
returns (
    LAST_DAY date)
as
declare variable NEXT_DAY date;
declare variable COUNTER integer;
begin
    NEXT_DAY = :REFERENCE_DATE;
    COUNTER = 0;
    while (:COUNTER < 33) do begin
        NEXT_DAY = :NEXT_DAY + 1;
        if (extract(month from :NEXT_DAY) = extract(month from :REFERENCE_DATE)) then begin
            LAST_DAY = :NEXT_DAY;
        end
        COUNTER = :COUNTER + 1;
    end
    suspend;
end`

Then to call it just execute:

`select last_day from last_day_of_month('02-23-2016')`

This will return `02-29-2016`

Answer (score 0):

```
select dateadd (month, -1,dateadd (-extract(day from current_date)+1 day to current_date)) First_day_month_ago 
from RDB$DATABASE 
union all
select dateadd (-extract(day from current_date)+1 day to current_date) First_day_current_month 
from RDB$DATABASE
```

Answer (score 0):

Migrating from MySQL I needed the FIRST_DAY and LAST_DAY functions. Here they are:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION FIRST_DAY(d TIMESTAMP)
RETURNS DATE
AS 
BEGIN
   RETURN CAST(d - EXTRACT(DAY FROM d) + 1 AS DATE); 
END
```

and

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION LAST_DAY(d TIMESTAMP)
RETURNS DATE
AS 
BEGIN
   RETURN DATEADD(1 MONTH TO FIRST_DAY(d)) - 1;  
END
```

And executing from isql:

```sql
SQL> SELECT first_day(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), last_day(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) FROM RDB$DATABASE rd;

  FIRST_DAY    LAST_DAY 
=========== =========== 
2020-08-01  2020-08-31
```

Answer (score 0):

but creating a function like this:

```html
create or alter function F_DAYSOFMONTH (
    LMONTH integer,
    LYEAR integer)
returns integer
as
declare variable LTMPDT DM_DATA;
declare variable LTMPDT2 timestamp;
begin
  SELECT CAST(CAST(:lmonth AS VARCHAR(10)) || '/01/' || CAST(:lyear AS VARCHAR(10)) AS TIMESTAMP) FROM RDB$DATABASE INTO :LTMPDT;

  LTMPDT2 = dateadd(1 month TO :LTMPDT);


  return datediff(DAY FROM :ltmpdt TO :LTMPDT2);;
end^

SET TERM ; ^
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FIRST_LAST_DAYOFMONTH(COMPARE_DATE TIMESTAMP)
RETURNS (FIRST_DAYOFOMONTH TIMESTAMP,LAST_DAYOFMONTH TIMESTAM)
AS
BEGIN
FIRST_DAYOFMONTH=COMPARE_DATE-(EXTRACT(DAY FROM :COMPARE_DATE)-1);
LAST_DAYOFMONTH=DATEADD(1 MONT TO :COMPARE_DATE)-1;
SUSPEND;
END^
```